# Alert Box doing validation but not showing massage on screen

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, macos

So all the function is working but I used alert for validation alert and error message which is working on windows system perfectly but not working on mac.
Does anyone have any idea?
Note: It is doing the validation but not showing the message on screen

```
protected void BtnBtnInsert_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

    {
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        string str;

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConString);

        int Status = 0;
        con.Open();

        String UpdateQuery;
        String SSN;

        SSN = TxtBxSSSN.Text.ToString().Trim();

        if (CheckValidSSNBeforeUpdate(SSN) == "1")
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('SSN already exists, record is updated.!')", true);
        }
        else
        {
            InsertNewEmployee();  
        }

        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: what does Console.WriteLine(CheckValidSSNBeforeUpdate(SSN) ); output?

Comment: What do you mean by it works in windows, but not in mac. Do you mean the mac browser Safari? Or when hosted on a mac system?

Comment: ON a mac system. I tried with chrome in mac still no luck.